# alert while loop javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, alert

Hiii there
I need some help with how i take out the alert("Du har inga behörighet!"); outside the while loop

```
while (userEnumerator.moveNext())
{
    var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
    var title = oUser.get_title();
    if (title == user.get_title())
    {
        if (document.getElementById("divTable").style.display == "")
        {
            $("#lblAnvandareNamn").text("Välkommen " + first + ", du inloggad som ansvarig!");
            $("#lblTryckhar").text("Vill tidrapportera?");
            document.getElementById("UppdateraStatus").style.display = "";
            document.getElementById("divTable").style.display = "none";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("divTable").style.display == "none")
        {
            $("#lblAnvandareNamn").text("Välkommen " + first + ", du inloggad som användare!");
            $("#lblTryckhar").text("Är du ansvarig?");
            document.getElementById("UppdateraStatus").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("divTable").style.display = "";
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Du har inga behörighet!");
    }
}
```

I only want to show that alert once.

Comment: Can you be more clear? What do you mean take it out the while loop? why? Btw, I did not downvote

Comment: I mean that it should not be repeated / displayed every time it loops through

Comment: i need to show alert just one time

Comment: @MiladFrancis do you want it to exit the loop once the alert has shown or continue looping but not show alert again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a flag tor remember if the alert should be displayed or not:

```
// By default the alert should not be displayed
var showAlert = false;

while (...) {
    if (title == user.get_title()) {
        ...
    } else {
        // Don't show the alert immediatly, but remember that it should be displayed
        showAlert = true;
    }
}

// Finally show the alert if required
if (showAlert) {
    alert("Du har inga behörighet!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag like

```
    var titleIsEqual = false;
    while (userEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oUser = userEnumerator.get_current();
                var title = oUser.get_title();
                if(title == user.get_title())
                {
                    if (document.getElementById("divTable").style.display == "") {
                        $("#lblAnvandareNamn").text("Välkommen " + first + ", du inloggad som ansvarig!");
                        $("#lblTryckhar").text("Vill tidrapportera?");
                        document.getElementById("UppdateraStatus").style.display = "";
                        document.getElementById("divTable").style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else if (document.getElementById("divTable").style.display == "none") {
                        $("#lblAnvandareNamn").text("Välkommen " + first + ", du inloggad som användare!");
                        $("#lblTryckhar").text("Är du ansvarig?");
                        document.getElementById("UppdateraStatus").style.display = "none";
                        document.getElementById("divTable").style.display = "";
                    }
                    return;
                }                    
                else
                {
                    titleIsEqual = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

if(titleIsEqual){
  alert("Du har inga behörighet!");
}
```

Comment: @MiladFrancis, no problem. You should 'accept' an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if you found the answer useful